# How to put a React application in a maintenance mode?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application that lives separately from the backend Rails API application and I would like to introduce a feature of putting the frontend app into maintenance mode and I can't come up with any good idea.

My client wants to have a button to click and so that when he clicks it, the app would go to a maintenance mode.

Since this is a React app, obviously the HTML is not rendered by any backend server (the backend API serves only for providing data to the frontend and as an admin panel) but by JS. I use `react-router` and I have many routes which render different components, those, in turn, make several API calls to the backend. I could put the backend in a maintenance mode and make the frontend app react on responses from the backend (503 Service Unavailable) but it would take a lot of effort and time since I'd have to modify all routes and sagas to make them react appropriately to the responses from the backend.

I am thinking of creating a separate branch holding just a maintenance page and have the customer to deploy this branch whenever he wants to instead of having the button to click. I've tried using Express.js middleware [Maintenance](https://github.com/likeastore/maintenance) but either it doesn't work or I don't know how to use it (I am pretty new to this). The app runs on an Express server on Node. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can create component <Maintenance /> and render it out in main App.js file before react-router <Switch .. > just add some variable in .env file to check if app is in maintenance mode. Should work just fine.

Comment: This sounds like a plan however it wouldn't go with the button. I guess, there is no easy way to do that in this case.

Comment: And it would also require app restart to load the new .env.

Comment: True. In that case, you can make an endpoint in your Rails API to check if maintenance mode is enable, but it would be extra XHR request. .env is better option, if you go in maintenance mode not very often.

Comment: I will go with separate branch and have my client deploy it whenever he needs to. He is educated in IT so it shouldn't be a problem for him.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet would be to have a simple index.html page for the maintenance mode. Then simply swap the index.html and maintenance_index.html. This is great since it bypasses all React in case there is something broken in there.

I'm not sure about the environment you are using for that Express server but you could use Bash to swap the files quickly and easily:

```sh
$ mv index.html tmp_index.html && mv maintenance_index.html index.html && mv tmp_index.html maintenance_index.html
```

Simple maintenance html:

```html
<!-- To use swap with index.html and invalidate web cache -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<style>
  body {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
      padding-top: 150px;
    }
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }

  body {
    font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
  }

  article {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>

<article>
  <h1>We&rsquo;ll be back soon!</h1>
  <div>
    <p>
      Sorry for the inconvenience but we&rsquo;re performing some maintenance at the moment.We&rsquo;ll be back online
      shortly!
    </p>
    <p>&mdash; The XX Team</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to me, your question universal, not just about react or frontend.
What we do is. We keep a record in table like is_maintenance or is_active and maintenance_msg.

And we provide this api to frontend and whenever a frontend start thier app, they hit this api first and then checks whether backend is active or not. If not show maintenance page and if it is working fine, then go like normal !
Maintenance message is used to show data to users about maintenance information.

So you can also make new api and table to store startup data. whatever data you wants to share to frontend before app starts.